# How to fix SCRIPT_NAME with PHP-FPM and Apache's mod_fastcgi?

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm

I have the following in my Apache conf to get PHP-FPM working:

```
FastCgiExternalServer /srv/www/fast-cgi-fake-handler -host 127.0.0.1:9000
AddHandler php-fastcgi .php
AddType text/html .php
Action php-fastcgi /var/www/cgi-bin
Alias /var/www/cgi-bin /srv/www/fast-cgi-fake-handler
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This works fine except that SCRIPT_NAME is always `/var/www/cgi-bin` and some scripts use SCRIPT_NAME to work out the location of the current script (vBulletin).

Google has plenty of solutions for Nginx but not a word for Apache.

Answer (score 2):

If you use RewriteRule in place of "Action" method, it will work out just fine

Given below is an example I used to in Apache to connect to FCGI::Daemon external fastcgi daemon process. This daemon can be considered as a perl's version of php-fpm.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example"
    ServerName www.example.com

    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    FastCGIExternalServer /var/www/fcgi-daemon/perl.fcgi -socket /var/run/fcgi-daemon.sock
    ScriptAlias /perl.fcgi /var/www/fcgi-daemon/perl.fcgi
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/example/cgi-bin>
    Options ExecCGI
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /perl.fcgi [L]
</Directory>
```

Note: "/var/www/fcgi-daemon/" has to exist! as blank directory.
Actual the method you used for php does not work out of box for perl daemon. SCRIPT_FILENAME was always /var/www/fcgi-daemon/perl.fcgi which never existed, leading to error. Using RewriteRule kept all the required environment variables in place and passed them along to perl fastcgi daemon.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when setting `FastCgiExternalServer` to a directory that exists (probably works for a file too) such as `/srv/www` then all the PHP variables were set correctly. However, all non-PHP content would serve as either `text/html` or `text/plain` which isn't very good. Also `DirectoryIndex` stopped having an effect which reminds me of [this question over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574690/sharing-php-cgi-between-apache-and-nginx) but I couldn't get anywhere with his solution of juggling absolute and relative paths.

The only relevant Google result for PHP-FPM, Apache and SCRIPT_NAME is [a comment by someone called Dimas](http://learnix.net/fastasscgi-part2) who says that [this method fixed it for him](http://personal.x-istence.com/post/2010/11/15/apache-modfastcgi-and-php-php-fpm), but I had no such luck.

I've resorted to setting `auto_prepend_file` in my php.ini to a file containing the following:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'];
unset($_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
unset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

Not the best solution but at least I don't have to manually edit vBulletin, Wordpress, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by ensuring that [cgi.fix-pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.fix-pathinfo) in your php.ini is set to 1.  That causes PHP to populate the $_SERVER array as you would expect when executing PHP as CGI/FastCGI on Apache.

Comment: I don't know why, but for me its the opposite. If I set it to 0, it works. And what does even this line mean *'You should fix your scripts to use SCRIPT_FILENAME rather than PATH_TRANSLATED'* ?

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/a/423965/118969 by ColtonCat above, is the best answer.
I've tried it using nginx (ssl-reverse-proxy) -> apache -> php53-fpm.

if using nginx (ssl-reverse-proxy) -> **apache + mod_php**, you can use **cgi.fix_pathinfo=0**